# index.html can only link to certain pages like google.com

Tags: apache2, raspberrypi, html

I edited the default apache2 Debian index page and placed 2 links for testing purposes, but only one link worked.

Question: Why can I link to sites like Yahoo and YouTube but the link to my insecure home page hosted at infoquest.com does not work (page not found)?

Below is a copy of the default apache2 Debian index page I created on my Raspberry Pi. To better understand my problem, notice the 2 href links I entered for testing. The 1st link to yahoo.com works. The issue is the second link to my "unsecured" website "youret.com" comes up with “page not found”.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang ="en">
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Creating Server Raspberry</title>
 </head>
  <body>
        <header>
        <h1> Your Expert Tutor <h1>
        </header>

<a href="https://www.yahoo.com"> alt="Your Expert Tutor">
<a href="https://www.youret.com"> alt="Your Expert Tutor">
  </body>
</html>
```

However, this page is found if a search is done from another browser. Why does the link yahoo.com work but the link youret.com fail when both pages are available?

Comment: Does the site exist? Is your firewall allowing access?

Comment: Thank you very much. The solution of changing https:// to http://  WORKS !!!

Answer (score 1):

Your web page contains multiple issues that are completely unrelated to running the web server on a Raspberry Pi – you can simply check and fix them in an HTML file on your working computer.

1. Your `<a>` tags should have a matching closing `</a>` tag. However, both Firefox and Chrome render two links as intended.
2. The [`<a>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) does not have an `alt` attribute. If you want some text to be displayed when you hover the mouse cursor over the link, use the [`title` attribute](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-title-attribute/).

So your first link should look like this, for example:

```html
<a href="https://www.yahoo.com" title="Your Expert Tutor">link text</a>
```

3. You’re saying your site is “unsecured” but are pointing to it with an `https://` link though. Clicking it results in an HTTPS error (related to `youret.com` as the link target, not your Raspberry Pi as the link source). Simply removing the `s` (meaning **s**ecure) from `https` helped in my case to reach `http://youret.com`.

   ```html
   <a href="http://youret.com">link text</a>
   ```